# My Compiler is giving the error message that the data member of a structure cannot be accessed because the structure variable is non-class type

Tags: c++, structure

This is a simple piece of code meant to use a separate structure to collect scores of P , C , M and use a function avg() to pass the structure variable to it and find the mean score of each student. I am using an array of 5 structure variables. Here is the code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct report
{
    public:
    int p,c,m;
};
double avg (report ob)
{
    double mean = ((ob.p) + (ob.c) + (ob.m))/3;
    return mean;
}
    int main()
    {
        report ob[5];
        int i;
        double mean;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Student num"<<" "<<i<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter P , C , M Marks"<<endl;
            cin>>ob.p;
            cin>>ob.c;
            cin>>ob.m;
        }
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Average marks of Student number"<<" "<<i<<endl;
            mean = avg(ob[i]);
            cout<<mean<<endl;
        }
    }
```

And the compiler's output:

```
Error : ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Users\us\Documents\Progs\ReportStructure.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\us\Documents\Progs\ReportStructure.cpp|22|error: 
> request for member 'p' in 'ob', which is of non-class type 'report
> [5]'|

C:\Users\us\Documents\Progs\ReportStructure.cpp|23|error: 

> request for member 'c' in 'ob', which is of non-class type 'report
> [5]'|

C:\Users\us\Documents\Progs\ReportStructure.cpp|24|error: `

> request for member 'm' in 'ob', which is of non-class type 'report
> [5]'|

`
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: `ob` is an array, not a `report`; `ob[i]` is a `report`, not an array.

Comment: How did you declare `ob`? What was your goal when you wrote a loop? What did you intend  to use `i` for, besides printing it? These are the sort of questions your rubber duck could ask. That's one way to troubleshoot, read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for that and more.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Student num"<<" "<<i<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter P , C , M Marks"<<endl;
            cin>>ob[i].p;
            cin>>ob[i].c;
            cin>>ob[i].m;
        }
```

Try accessing the ith element like so.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but since this is a struct, and not a class declaration, I think :

```
struct report
{
    public:
    int p,c,m;
};
```

should be :

```
struct report
{
    int p,c,m;
};
```

Then, ob being an array of struct, I think you need to specify an index, in order to access specific field :

```
cin>>ob.p;
cin>>ob.c;
cin>>ob.m;
```

Should probably be :

```
cin>>ob[i].p;
cin>>ob[i].c;
cin>>ob[i].m;
```

Comment: `struct` members are `public` by default, so the first part of the answer should not change anything.

Comment: You ARE wrong.   In C++, a struct definition can have `public`, `private`, and `protected` access modifiers.  A class and a struct are functionally identical, except that default access is `private` for a class, and `public` for a struct.       Of course, if the struct definition is to be used in both C and C++ code, the access specifiers cannot be present (since `public`, `private`, and `protected` are not part of standard C at all)